# c# Telegram.Bot SendMediaGroup Отправить одним постом фото и видео

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Отправляю сообщение в канал:

```
 var photos = post.Photo.Select(x => new InputMediaPhoto(x)).ToList();
                
                botClient = new TelegramBotClient(TelegramToken);
                Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                               chatId: Channel,
                               inputMedia: photos
                           );
```

**photos** - список с изображениями.
Или:

```
 var videos = Video.Select(x => new InputMediaVideo(x)).ToList();
                   
                    botClient = new TelegramBotClient(TelegramToken);

                    Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
                                    chatId: Channel,
                                    inputMedia: videos
                                );
```

**videos** - список с видеофайлами.

Как можно в один пост добавить вложение разных типов (фото+ видео либо фото + аудио)?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inputMedia` принимает тип `IEnumerable<IAlbumInputMedia>` где `IAlbumInputMedia` наследует `IInputMedia`, а `IInputMedia` общий для всего медиа, поэтому можно просто склеить коллекции.

```cs
var media = post.Video.Select(x => (IInputMedia)new InputMediaVideo(x))
                      .Concat(post.Photo.Select(x => (IInputMedia)new InputMediaPhoto(x)));

// вы уверены что хотите каждый раз пересоздавать нового бота при отправке сообщения?
botClient = new TelegramBotClient(TelegramToken);

Message[] messages = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(
    chatId: Channel,
    inputMedia: media
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Comment: @aepot
Подскажите почему у меня не работает, повторил пример, но альбом не отправляется 
List<string> result = new List<string>() { "033122.png", "101144.png" };
                var mediaFiles = result.Select(x => (IInputMedia)new InputMediaPhoto(x));
                Message[] messages = await client.SendMediaGroupAsync(
      chatId: chatIdUser,
      media: (IEnumerable<IAlbumInputMedia>)mediaFiles);

Comment: @ИванРудаков задайте лучше новый вопрос

Comment: @aepot хорошо
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1461172/c-telegram-bot-sendmediagroup-%d0%9e%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc