# c# Telegram.Bot SendMediaGroup Отправить альбом фото одним сообщением

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Подскажите как отправить альбом с фотографиями одним сообщением
Пробовал так

```
List<string> result = new List<string>() { "033122.png", "101144.png" };
var mediaFiles = result.Select(x => (IInputMedia)new InputMediaPhoto(x));
Message[] messages = await client.SendMediaGroupAsync(
    chatId: chatIdUser,
    media: (IEnumerable<IAlbumInputMedia>)mediaFiles);
```

так

```
foreach (var image in result)
{
    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Open(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        streamArray.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(stream, image)));
    };
    Message[] messages = await client.SendMediaGroupAsync(
        chatId: chatIdUser,
        media: streamArray;
    }
}
```

так

```
List<string> result = new List<string>() { "033122.png", "101144.png" };
List<FileStream> streams = new List<FileStream>
{
    System.IO.File.OpenRead("033122.png"),
    System.IO.File.OpenRead("101144.png"),
};

List<InputMediaPhoto> media = new List<InputMediaPhoto>();

foreach (var stream in streams)
{
    media.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(stream, stream.Name)));
}
await client.SendMediaGroupAsync(chatIdUser, media);
```

Comment: Отформатируйте пожалуйста код, читать невозможно

Comment: @aepot готово, отформатировал

Comment: код из вопроса работает, но в случае работы с коллекцией фото, сомнительно, так как Stream не работает в коллекциях. 

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1260645/c-telegram-bot-api-%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BC-ialbuminputmedia

Comment: Непонятно, как оно работает и как должно работать.

Answer (score 0):

//TODO set foundPhotos, user.Tgid

```
        List<FileStream> streams = new List<FileStream>();
        List<InputMediaPhoto> phts = new List<InputMediaPhoto>();
        try
        {
            foreach (string p in foundPhotos)
            {
                FileStream s = System.IO.File.OpenRead(p);
                streams.Add(s);
                phts.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(new InputFile(s, Path.GetFileName(p))));
            }
            Task t = Task.Run(async () => await client.SendMediaGroupAsync(user.Tgid, phts));
            t.Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO
        }
        finally
        {
            foreach (var s in streams)
                s.Dispose();
            phts.Clear();
        }
```

Comment: @Алекскей потоки данных нельзя хранить в коллекциях, ваш код не рабочий явно, я пробовал такой подход и это не работало

Comment: "потоки данных нельзя хранить в коллекция" - с чего вы это взяли? Код 100% рабочий, он в релизе в сданном проекте. .net6

Answer (score 0):

Пример кода который работает для отправки массива фото, так как InputMediaPhoto требует объект Stream мы не можем передать его коллекцией, но можно использовать другой подход

```
List<Task<Stream>> streams = new List<Task<Stream>>();
```

использовать коллекцию потоков, которые мы вызовем для InputMediaPhoto. Код взят из готового решения, поэтому выкладываю весь класс решения для этой задачи

```
  using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using Telegram.Bot;
    using Telegram.Bot.Exceptions;
    using Telegram.Bot.Polling;
    using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
    using Telegram.Bot.Types;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using Example.Model.Message;
    using Example.Model;
    using System.Windows.Threading;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Example.Model.AutopostingModel;
    
    namespace Example
    {
        public class Publish_Chat
        {
            DataContext db;
            CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken;
            ITelegramBotClient? botClient;
            ListBox ListBoxPosting { get; set; }
            int ReloadCount = 0;
            private Label LblStatus { get; set; }
            public Publish_Chat(DataContext db, CancellationTokenSource cancellationToken, ITelegramBotClient? botClient, Label LblStatus, ListBox ListBoxPosting)
            {
                this.db = db;
                this.cancellationToken = cancellationToken;
                this.botClient = botClient;
                this.LblStatus = LblStatus;
                this.ListBoxPosting = ListBoxPosting;
            }
            public async Task Publish_Start()
            {
                try
                {
                    List<AutoPostingDB> publish_List = db.AutoPostingDB.Include(x => x.ListPublishChat).Include(y => y.ImagePostingDB).Where(x => x.TbStatusPublish == "Не опубликовано").ToList();
                    botClient = await telegramBot(botClient);
                    if (botClient == null)
                        return;
                    while (publish_List.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        publish_List = db.AutoPostingDB.Include(x => x.ListPublishChat).Include(y => y.ImagePostingDB).Where(x => x.TbStatusPublish == "Не опубликовано").ToList();
                        if(publish_List.Count() > 0)
                        await Task.Delay(30000);
                        List<Task<Stream>> streams = new List<Task<Stream>>();
                        List<InputMediaPhoto> media = new List<InputMediaPhoto>();
                        foreach (var image in publish_List)
                        {
                            if (DateTime.Now < image.Publish)
                                continue;
                            foreach (var chats in image.ListPublishChat)
                            {
                                if (chats.PublishCheck)
                                {
                                    media.Clear();
                                    streams.Clear();
                                    foreach (var mediaItem in image.ImagePostingDB)
                                    {
                                        streams.Add(ImageAdd(mediaItem.Image));
                                    }
                                    foreach (var stream in streams)
                                    {
                                        media.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(await stream, "photo.jpeg")));
                                    }
                                    var tempMedia = media.FirstOrDefault();
                                    if (tempMedia != null)
                                        tempMedia.Caption = image.Message;
                                    if (chats != null && media.Count() > 0)
                                    {
                                        var message = await botClient.SendMediaGroupAsync(chats.ChatId, media, protectContent: true);
                                    }
                                    else
                                    if (image.Message != null && chats != null)
                                    {
                                        await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chats.ChatId, image.Message);
                                    }
                                }
                                image.TbStatusPublish = "Опубликовано";
                                lock (this)
                                    db.SaveChanges();
                                var publish = db.AutoPostingDB.Include(x => x.ListPublishChat).Include(y => y.ImagePostingDB).ToList();
                                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                                {
                                    ListBoxPosting.ItemsSource = publish;
                                    ListBoxPosting.Items.Refresh();
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    string message = ex.Message.ToString();
                    if (message.Contains(message))
                        await Reload_Publish_Start();
                }
            }
            async Task Reload_Publish_Start()
            {
                await Publish_Start();
            }
            async Task<Stream> ImageAdd(byte[]? bytes)
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                await memStream.WriteAsync(bytes!, 0, bytes!.Length);
                memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                return memStream;
            }
            async Task<ITelegramBotClient?> telegramBot(ITelegramBotClient? botClient)
            {
                ITelegramBotClient telegramBot = botClient!;
                if (telegramBot == null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var tokenBot = db.BotInfo.FirstOrDefault();
                        if (tokenBot != null && tokenBot.Token != null && tokenBot.Token.Length == 0)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Добавьте токен бота");
                            return telegramBot;
                        }
                        telegramBot = new TelegramBotClient(tokenBot!.Token!);
                        User me = await telegramBot.GetMeAsync(); /// бот запущен
                        //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        //{
                        //    LblStatus.Content = "Бот запущен";
                        //});
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        ReloadCount++;
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        {
                            LblStatus.Content = $"Ошибка автопостинга, попытка перезагрузки: №{ReloadCount}";
                        });
                    }
                }
                else
                    return telegramBot;
                return telegramBot;
            }
        }
    }
```